# On or over - - which one should I use?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, types-of-sentences

Which one of the two is correct/ natural?

a) I shouldn't have wasted money on this
b) I shouldn't have wasted money over this

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any good reason why wasting ***time*** should be more accommodating of the preposition ***over*** than wasting ***money***. But [here's the evidence...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waste%20time%20over%20it%2Cwaste%20time%20on%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaste%20time%20over%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwaste%20time%20on%20it%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwaste%20time%20over%20it%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwaste%20time%20on%20it%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

As you can see, ***over*** is in decline even there - but it's by no means "uncommon / unusual", even today. [On the other hand,...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=waste%20money%20over%20it%2Cwaste%20money%20on%20it&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwaste%20money%20on%20it%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwaste%20money%20on%20it%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

...shows that *waste **money over** it* is too rare to even plot on the chart.

My advice is to stick with ***on*** to introduce the syntactic "object" of ***to waste***, since that's obviously the way things are going. There's not really any meaning to the question ***Why*** is this change taking place? - just accept that it ***is***.